# Array being treated as string by angular with loopback backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I am new to angular and have been trying to get ng-repeat working, but have been unable to do so. The backend is based on Loopback. Here is my code.

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="item in getCityList" value="{{item}}">{{item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

If `getCityList`is hardcoded as an array, it works e.g. `$scope.getCityList = ["Karachi", "Lahore"]` and each item forms an individual select option, i.e. `Karachi` and `Lahore`

However, if I use a function defined on a Loopback model instead, e.g. `self.getCityList = Application.getCityList();`, the two city names are not printed individually, but rather as one select option i.e. `["Karachi", "Lahore"]`

It seems that `Application.getCityList()` is outputting the array as string. Is there any way to treat it as an array instead?

Here is the code for `Application.getCityList()`

```
Application.getCityList = function (cb) { var areaList = ["Karachi", "Lahore"]; cb(null, areaList); };
```

Comment: I can't see any problem.. you provided the same `array` in both examples.

Comment: Are you sure it's a string? Have you done debugging? It could also be a 2D array.

Comment: you should favor using `ng-options` over `ng-repeat` when working with select lists.

Comment: `console.log(typeof Application.getCityList())` will tell you the type.

Comment: The problem is in the output. The hardcoded array in the controller ends up forming two select options, Karachi and Lahore individually, whereas if I use Application.getCityList(), only a single select option is formed, i.e. ["Karachi", "Lahore"]

Comment: please post the code for the `getCityList()` function;  right now we can only take your word for the fact that it is returning a string;  if it is indeed returning a string, then you will either have to correct that function or manually parse the result.

Comment: it is *unlikely* that you are getting a string;  `ng-repeat` wouldn't iterate over a string, you would receive an empty list, rather than the string as a single option.  see http://plnkr.co/edit/YapEVxE8VtckG5O4fzsO?p=preview for this.  it is much more likely that it is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: the typeof returns object. The code for getCityList has already been posted above

Comment: You posted the HTML. You didn't show the code for `getCityList()` in the JS. We need to see the code that the array originates from.

Comment: self.getCityList = Application.getCityList(); Application is a model in the loopback app

Comment: @AsfandyarSheikh That's not what I meant. What is the code for `Application.getCityList`?

Comment: Application.getCityList = function (cb) {
    var areaList = ["Karachi", "Lahore"];
    cb(null, areaList);
  };

Comment: There's no `return` statement?

Comment: you should [edit] your question with new code, rather than posting code in the comments.

Comment: @4castle It is a callback function. The rest api gives the desired output which means the function is working. The problem lies with the parsing of data

Comment: And guys, no need to downvote the question for your own inability to answer it

Comment: I don't think that is the reason for the downvotes.  The reason for the downvotes are probably related to the reason that I voted for closure;  you haven't presented a clear problem that makes sense, and haven't provided a [mcve] demonstrating your issue.  As it stands now, it's not even clear if the latest updates are going to help solve the problem, since you posted a function that expects a callback when asked for your code, but the calling code you have doesn't supply one, so it's still not possible to even create a failing example on your behalf.

Comment: and just for the record, you aren't going to capture people's attention to help you solve the problem when you suggest they don't have the ability to answer the problem.

Comment: it *appears* as though you posted your node server code for the `getCityList` function, not the angular code (which seems to have the same name).  It is the angular part that makes the API call and receives the result that is important here, not the server side code.

Comment: it is also possible that you are not using an angular controller at all, and instead are somehow writing the result of `getCityList` on the server into the HTML content.  You really haven't shown enough to know for certain, however, so I'm just tossing out possible ideas.  However, that's why this question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: If I didn't know the answer to the problem, I would upvote. The issue is that you didn't give enough information for anyone to know what the problem was, so I voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
self.getCityList = Application.getCityList();
```

getCityList takes a callback method. It does not return the data, but pass it to the callback.

```
Application.getCityList(function(err,data) {
    self.getCityList = data;
});
```

Should work